# How do you call the main launcher activity from another activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, program-entry-point

In my program I have an activity that gets launched when the application opens. If I open a couple more activities, how can I go back to the main activity? In the intent filter, the name of the activity is "android.intent.action.MAIN", and it will not allow me to call startActivity() on it. What do I do?

Comment: don't think you can just call startActivity with a activity from another application. I think your only bet is implicit intent.

Answer (score 4):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Let's say your activity stack is as follows... MainActivity > Activity1 > Activity2> Activity3,
Running the code above will close activities 1 & 2 and resume MainActivity